# Check Wether an XtraForm is open or Not

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

​In Normal Winform application I use given below code which first check the specific Form is open and if condition is True
then use its any public function.

```
if (Application.OpenForms["Main"] != null)
            {
                var Main = Application.OpenForms["Main"] as Main;
                if (Main != null)
                    Main.sendjob();
            }
```

Now I am working on Devexpress Xtraform Application and this piece of code not works .please Suggest me Suitable code For Devexpress Winform

Thanks​

Comment: Does the form named Main? and whether it is of type `Main`? Other than that there is nothing special in `XtraForm`. This piece of code should work.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes Name and Type is Main .But it is really not working.

Comment: Did you debug the application? Which statement is false?

Comment: yes I debug  This condition is not getting True. if (Application.OpenForms["Main"] != null)

Comment: Try this `var main = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Main>().FirstOrDefault();` and see if you can get the instance.

Comment: I Dont know what was the problem with old code But now it is working like a charm

Comment: By the way, have you tried executing this code? foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) Debug.WriteLine(form.Name);